# Como obtener el registro anterior de una misma fecha sin usar el Id

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Tengo la siguiente situación: tengo una tabla, donde llevo los registros diario de un medidor de agua. Mientras que fui tomando una lectura diaria y capturando la en el sistema , no tuve problema ya que me reflejada bien el consumo diario. El problema se me presenta, cuando hago mas de una lectura al día ya que tienen la misma fecha de registro. Cuando hago dos capturas de la lectura del medidor, el mismo día en distintos horarios, en lugar de obtener el registro anterior **( 1 )** me va al que tiene la fecha anterior **( 2 )**. y necesitando el registro del ejemplo **( 1 )** para poder hacer el calculo de consumo durante el día.

**Ej:**

**1 -El registro anterior de la fecha del día 26-03-2019:**

> 2019-03-26 06:53:37   2019-03-26  339304.00   Mar 2.02

**2 -El registro que me devuelve la consulta SQL:**

> 2019-03-25 09:09:57   2019-03-25  339102.00   Lun 5.95

La captura de la lectura, se puede realizar, toda el mismo día por lo que no puedo usar el **id**, ya que el operador del sistema puede cargar de forma desordenadas las lecturas.

> (Ej: primero me puede cargar la 2019-03-26 y después cargar la
>   2019-03-25.)

A continuación le dejo la consulta y la pantalla donde se me esta presentando el error para ver si me pueden ayudar.

Gracias.

**Consulta para obtener el registro anterior:**

```
SELECT medidor_dias.* FROM (`medidor_dias`) WHERE `fecha_medida` <  '2019-03-26'   AND `id_tipo_medidor` = '4'  AND `medidor_dias`.`fecha_medida` >= '2019-02-26' AND `medidor_dias`.`fecha_medida` <= '2019-03-28'  ORDER BY `id_tipo_medidor` ASC, `fecha_medida` DESC , medidor_dias.hora_ejecutado DESC LIMIT 1
```

**Imagen del Error día 26-03-2019:**

En la imagen se puede ver, que el día: 26-03-2019 se capturo dos veces por lo que muestran dos registros. En la segunda lectura de ese día es el  acumulado total de las dos lecturas, con respecto al día 25-03-2019. El valor que debería ir en el consumo de la segunda lectura es de **2.47** y no de **4.49** que es el que tiene. La formula que estoy usando para el calculo es la siguiente **(Ultimo registro - Registro anterior =  consumo)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Qué es lo que quieres obtener y qué tipo de comparación es el que quieres hacer? ¿Necesitas los datos ordenados? ¿En qué orden? ¿Necesitas filtrar los datos? ¿Bajo qué criterio? ... Eso es lo que debes explicarnos, más que decirnos que antes todo era estupendo pero ahora no funciona. Si ahora no funciona debes decirnos lo que necesitas y cómo lo necesitas de una forma clara, sin mezclar explicaciones del pasado. Saludos.

Comment: Hola buenas tarde,  lo que necesito es sacar el consumo de agua diario, el cual si lo tengo. El problema me surge cuando hago dos lecturas en el día porque me la compara contra la fecha anterior y no con el registro anterior y no lo puedo hacer por Id

Comment: No entiendo precisamente a qué te refieres con eso de las dos lecturas diarias. ¿cuál es el criterio para esas dos lecturas diarias? ¿qué quieres decir con que te las compara con el día anterior? ¿por qué no usas la fecha actual para filtrar?

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Indica exactamente el resultado quieres obtener para esos datos de ejemplo. Saludos.

Comment: Ya he actualizado la pregunta. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Por qué no nos pasas la estructura en SQL? ¿Has tenido algún problema con el volcado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí dejo la solución que le di a mi pregunta, por si alguien mas le hace falta. En esta solución tuve que hacer un re-acomodo del **id** de mi **tabla**. Esto lo puede realizar porque este **id**, no forma parte de ninguna clave forania y solo lo utilizo para el editar y borrar el registro, en caso que se requiera. Gracias a todos por su ayuda.

```
SET @a = 0;
ALTER TABLE medidor_dias DROP id;
ALTER TABLE medidor_dias ADD id int NOT NULL ;
UPDATE medidor_dias  SET id = @a:=@a+1    ORDER BY `fecha_medida` ASC , medidor_dias.hora_ejecutado ASC ;
ALTER TABLE `medidor_dias` ADD INDEX(`id`);
ALTER TABLE `medidor_dias` CHANGE `id` `id` INT(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

;